# How to add unbound button column after assigning datasource to DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have the below code to assign `datasource` to a `DataGridView`

```
Private Sub LoadDataForDataGrid()
        setconnection()
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet()
        cmd.CommandText = "select tj.jb_item_id as [Job Item Id], tj.jb_item_no as [Part #], tj.jb_item_name as [Part name], ti.Unit_price as Price, tj.jb_job_item_qty as Quantity, tj.jb_job_total as [Total Price] from tbl_jobitem tj, tblitementry_list ti where tj.jb_job_card_id='" & JobCardID & "' and ti.Item_no=tj.jb_item_no"
        adp4.SelectCommand = cmd
        adp4.Fill(ds1)
        adp4.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cnn.Close()
        Me.DGServiceDetails.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        CreateUnboundButtonColumn()//this will create an extra column with the added rows
End Sub
```

Now since I wanted to add `Delete` functionality to each row with a `Delete button` on each row and the above function is called after adding each record to the table `tbl_jobitem` and below is the `CreateUnboundButtonColumn` method which I got from **[this source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zkatshfa(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)**

```
Private Sub CreateUnboundButtonColumn()

        Dim buttonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn

        With buttonColumn
            .HeaderText = "Action"
            .Name = "Delete"
            .Text = "Delete"
        End With
        Me.DGServiceDetails.Rows.Insert(0, buttonColumn)
End Sub
```

But the above function adds Delete button on each call with extra column added everytime to each row and thus increasing number of columns with `delete button` each time. I tried adding it as design part by clicking on `Edit Columns` and adding it as `DataGridViewButtonColumn` which worked well and added Delete button to each row but I wasn't able to attach event handler to it. So any idea or light on this problem is highly appreciated.

> I am tagging C# here because solutions with C# is also accepted

Comment: I changed **Add Unbound Column**  and **Set Text of Unbound Button Column** in my answer and added a more simple way to set the `Text` of button: `deleteButton.Text="Delete"; deleteButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add Unbound Column

To add Unbound column:

```
var deleteButton=new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
deleteButton.Name="dataGridViewDeleteButton";
deleteButton.HeaderText="Delete";
deleteButton.Text="Delete";
deleteButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(deleteButton);
```

### Set Text of Unbound Button Column

To show "Delete" text on each button:

```
deleteButton.Text="Delete";
deleteButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue=true;
```

Also as another option specially when you want to set the text of button to different values, you can use [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` and Set the value of those cells:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //If this is header row or new row, do nothing
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;

    //If formatting your desired column, set the value
    if (e.ColumnIndex=this.dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index)
    {
        e.Value = "Delete";
    }
}
```

### Handle Click on Cell

You can handle [`CellClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` for example:

```
void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //if click is on new row or header row
    if( e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //Handle Button Column Click
    if( e.ColumnIndex  == dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index)
    {
        //Do the stuff for first button click
    }
}
```

**When does the event occur?**

1. This event occurs when a cell is clicked.
2. It also occurs when the user presses and releases the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key while a button cell or check box cell has focus.

**How to check if my desired cell clicked?**
If you know the index of your desired column is 4 for example, you can check:

```
if( e.ColumnIndex  == 4)
{ 
    //Do the stuff for your desired button click
    MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked");         
}
```

If you know the name of your desired column is dataGridViewDeleteButton for example, you can check:

```
if( e.ColumnIndex  == dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index)
{
     //Do the stuff for your desired button click
}
```

**Where can I find the data of row of clicked celll?**

```
//Here is the row object
var row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]

//Value of cell 0 of the row
this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value

//Value of IdTextBoxColumn cell
this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["IdTextBoxColumn"].Value
```

Comment: Perfect buddy.. Thanks much.. :)